# How to trigger Github Action's workflow dispatch event through curl with string input in json format

Tags: json, curl, github-actions

I have a workflow in Github Actions with a workflow_dispatch event trigger. I expect a string input in json format. The workflow's yml looks something like this:

```
name: Json parse test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      parameters_json:
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    name: Json parse test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Parse json input
        id: json
        run: |
          echo ${{ fromJson(github.event.inputs.parameters_json).targetPlatform }}
```

I want to trigger this workflow through a request with curl the way it is described [here](https://docs.github.com/es/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)

When i run the workflow manually through Github's web page it runs fine.
[image]

My problem is when I try to trigger the workflow through a curl request with

> curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <my token>" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" [https://api.github.com/repos/\](https://api.github.com/repos/%5C)<owner>/<my repo>/actions/workflows/json_parse_test.yml/dispatches -d '{"ref":"dev","inputs":{"parameters_json":"{"targetPlatform":"asd","param":45}"}}'

it throws the following error and the workflow does not run

```
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

If I pass a normal string (without json format, e.g "something") as input, the workflows gets triggered as expected, i.e. there is no problem with the curl code.

So, my question is: is there any syntax to send a string input with json format to get around this parsing issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to escape the nested JSON? Example: https://jqplay.org/s/2XujtIp-ySN

Comment: I highly recommend using the GitHub CLI for this; `gh workflow run` lets you pass parameters and helps with the escaping.

Comment: @Azeem thank you so much, that solves my problem. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Miguel: You're welcome! Sure. Also, as mentioned above in the comments, you might want to work with [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) more often. It comes in quite handy in these situations.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, GitHub CLI works as well but i'm using this as part of a tool that other users will use. That would require for them to get GitHub CLI installed which I'm trying to avoid. Thanks too.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Azeem who answered this in the question's comments.

To solve this issue you should escape the double quotes in the nested json input.

> "inputs":{"parameters_json":"{\"targetPlatform\":\"asd\",\"param\":45}"

Resulting in the curl code:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <my token>" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<my repo>/actions/workflows/json_parse_test.yml/dispatches -d '{"ref":"dev","inputs":{"parameters_json":"{\"targetPlatform\":\"asd\",\"param\":45}"}}'
```